# To_datetime in pandas module

Tags: pandas, datetime

This is a followup from a question which i had asked earlier: [File size increased after imported Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62013903/file-size-increased-after-imported-pandas?noredirect=1#comment109681461_62013903)

I have the following code:

```
pd.to_datetime(xl_file.index, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

in this code to make it work i have to use `import pandas as pd` is there a way i can get this code to work without having to import the entire pandas package. I need to do it this way because the size of the  `.exe` file increases dramatically.

Comment: from pandas import to_datetime ... this should work, isnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import the to_datetime function, rather than the entire package.

```
from pandas import to_datetime

val = to_datetime("2020-01-01", format='%Y-%m-%d')

print(val)
```

Output:

```
2020-01-01 00:00:00
```